# SQL Server 2012. Procedimiento almacenado

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una estructura de tablas **maestro-detalle** de *Presupuestos* y otra **maestro-detalle** de *Pedidos*. Si se acepta el *Presupuesto* se crea automáticamente un *Pedido* nuevo que tiene un campo autonumérico con los datos del *Presupuesto*.
Simplificándolo queda así:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[presupuestos_validar]

@numpresupuesto int

insert into pedidos (numpresupuesto, fechapresupuesto, codiusuario)

select numpresupuesto, fechapresupuesto, codiusuario
from presupuestos
where numpresupuesto = @numpresupuesto
```

Aquí ya tengo el pedido nuevo creado con un *numpedido* autogenerado cuyo valor debería enviar al siguiente script que copia los datos de la tabla detalle:

```
DECLARE @numpedido int;

insert into detallepedido(numpedido, referencia, articulo, cantidad, precio)
select numpresupuesto, referencia, articulo, cantidad, precio
from detallepresupuesto
where numpresupuesto = @numpresupuesto

select @numpedido = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

El problema que tengo es que no sé cómo hacer que el valor autogenerado del campo *numpedido* (no es autonumérico) de la tabla *pedidos* se guarde también en la tabla *detallepedido*.

Comment: Por favor, describe en el título el problema _específico_ que estás teniendo. Lee [ask].

Comment: Creo que se puede resolver con la clausula OUTPUT, pero necesito más detalles para estar seguro. Comparte la estructura de las tablas con datos de entrada y resultados esperados.